# String are overlapping on display in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[Check here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEXr2.jpg) I added an image view and added images to the table view but the display overlaps when I run the application. It shows an image over another image once you attempt scrolling down the table. How do I fix this? Here is the code.

So there is an array that displays the title and subtitle of the atms and for every instance of a title, I tried to display a picture that represents it. But the display starts the overlap pictures on each other.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "atmCell", for: indexPath)
    var row = 0;

    cell.textLabel?.text = AtmList.instance.atms[indexPath.row].title
    cell.textLabel?.textColor=UIColor.black
    cell.textLabel?.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = AtmList.instance.atms[indexPath.row].subtitle

    let cellImage: UIImageView!
    cellImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 290, y: 39, width: 70, height: 70))
    cellImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cellImage.layer.masksToBounds=true
    cellImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    cellImage.layer.masksToBounds=true
    //  cellImage.image
    //let imgName = "Icon\((atms[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "title") as! String)"

    if cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "W" {
         cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "wemaBank_pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "A"  {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "AccessBank_pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "C"  {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "CitiBank_pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "D"  {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "DiamondBank_pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "H"  {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "HeritageBank_Pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "P"  {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "ProvidusBank_pin")
    } else if (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!])! == "F" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 2))!])! == "D" {
       cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "FidelityBank_pin")
    }else if (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!])! == "F" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index(after: (cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!))!])! == "C" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "FCMB_pin")
    } else if  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!])! == "F" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 5))!])! == "C" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "FCMB_pin")
    } else if  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!])! == "U" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 3))!])! == "o" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "UnionBank_pin")
    }else if cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "G"  {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "GTBank_pin")
    }else if   cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "G" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 1))!])! == "U" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "GTBank_pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "F"  {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "FirstBank_pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "K"  {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "KeystoneBank_pin")
    }else if cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "S" && (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 2))!])! == "y" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "skyeBank_pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "E"  {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "ecoBank_pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "Z"  {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "ZenithBank_pin")
    }else if (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!])! == "U" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index(after: (cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!))!])! == "b" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "UBA_pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "U" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 4))!])! == "y" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "UnityBank_pin")
    } else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "S" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 4))!])! == "b" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "StanbicIBTC_pin")
    } else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "S" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 4))!])! == "d" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "StandardCharteredBank_pin")
    } else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "S" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 3))!])! == "r" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "SterlingBank")
    }else if (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!])! == "S" &&   (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index(after: (cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!))!])! == "U" {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "SuntrustBank_pin")
    }else if  cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "U" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text!.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 4))!])! == "e" {
       cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "UBA_pin")
    }
    cell.addSubview(cellImage)

     return cell
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but replace code like `if cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!] == "W" {` with code like `if AtmList.instance.atms[indexPath.row].title.hasPrefix("W") {`.

Comment: And replace code like `if (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!])! == "F" &&  (cell.textLabel?.text![(cell.textLabel?.text!.index((cell.textLabel?.text?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 2))!])! == "D" {` with code like `if AtmList.instance.atms[indexPath.row].title.hasPrefix("FD") {`

Comment: `cell.addSubview()` in `cellForRowAt` is never a good idea because cells are reused. Also, as said by @rmaddy, prefer relying on the data source (`AtmList.instance.atms`) instead of the cell label. Also, it'd be nice if objects inside `AtmList.instance.atms` had a String property `imageName`, could avoid you all this in that method.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy

Comment: I'll fix that. Thanks @Larme

Comment: What's the code of the `ATMCell` file? You seem to do a `addSubview()`, and since cells are reused (that can be seen on the image part), that's an issue.

Comment: @Larme how do i fix this?   `cell.addSubview()`

Comment: Do it only ONCE per cell. What's the code of your ATMCell?

Comment: Just added some more codes @Larme do they help?

Comment: The Cell Class I meant.

Comment: Does not have a cell class. I Call  the cell from the mainstoryboard @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the height to `UITableViewCell` as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 120 // Assign the height as per your view
}
```

and set your image on your `UITableViewCell` as:

```
    let cellImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 290, y: 39, width: 70, height: 70))
    cellImage.clipsToBounds = true
    cellImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cellImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cellImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

But again your are creating image on cell reload, so it will be overlapped. In that case you should use a custom table cell [custom_cell_tutorial](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/) or just remove previous image view before creating a new object of `UIImageView` as:

```
    for view in cell.contentView.subviews where view is UIImageView {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let cellImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 290, y: 39, width: 70, height: 70))
    cellImage.clipsToBounds = true
    cellImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cellImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cellImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Comment: this does not solve the problem. I have two pictures displaying on top of each other @Ankit Jayaswal

Comment: Do you want to show both images in single table cell?

Comment: Just added a picture to show you how it displays. you see how the texts are on top of each other? that's what happens with the images too @Ankit Jayaswal

Comment: Updated the answer